# VS Code .py ModuelNotFoundError no moduel named 'pyodbc'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyodbc

I'm currently working in VS code; wanting to interact with an .mdb file.

```
File "d:/UDtools/CostEstimator/vsWorkspace/pyOdbcv1.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

pip installed in cmd, pip installed again in VS terminal: Requirement already satisfied.
```

I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: did you try restarting VS

Comment: How are you running your python file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the module "`pyodbc`" you installed is not installed in the VSCode environment you are currently using.

1. Check the installation tool "`pip`". When we use 'pip' to install a module, the source of 'pip' determines where the module exists. Use "`pip --version`" to check if it comes from the current environment:

   [image]

   (If not, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal, VSCode will automatically enter the current environment.)
2. Install the module. Use 'pip' to install the module in the currently selected environment: "`pip install pyodbc`" or "`pip3 install pyodbc`"
3. Check the installation package. "`pip list`":

   [image]
4. Run:

   [image]

More: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Thank you!  I had been using spyder; migrated to VScode, have been learning python backwards and the matrix can be hard some times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the python extension to run you files. Then you are using python in a virtual envirnment to run python and not the system python. so even if you installed a package, as long as you did not install it in the venv python vs code won't find it.
To test this run your .py file from the command line and see if you get the same error.
if you don't then reconfigure you python interpreter in vs code or install the package in the vnev.

Comment: Thank you!  Finally got the whole flow of things figured out. Appreciate your super helpful answer to a noob question!